# Kofax page rotation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6, kofax

I made a custom Kofax (v. 7.5) custom module that rotate every page in the documents, I have used VB6 and it works! But now there is a new version of Kofax (v. 10) that use VS10, my module doesn't work, I have isolated the problem is the rotation function, here how I use it.

```
Private acmApp As AscentCaptureModule.Application
```

....

```
acmApp.SelectMenuItem KfxScanMenuPageRotateAndSaveLeft, True
```

I repeat on Kofax 7.5 it works but on Kofax 10 no. This is the error message:

```
Error: 2104 Parameter out of bounds. scan 0
```

I've already check the function is supported on the new version it is the same.

Someone can help me? Thank you!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your requirement let me know. Because recently I faced issues related to Page rotation and I resolved it.. I Think I might help you. Note: In Kofax the Page gets automatically rotated whenever it is introduce into OCR and incase you rotate the image manually the data will get lost at the validation stage.

Answer (score 0):

you should always check the latest documentation

http://services.kofax.com/support/products/capture/10.1/documentation.php

There is an API guide in there for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug of Kofax, the id of the KfxScanMenuPageRotateAndSaveLeft function (in v. 10) isn't the same than the older version (v. 7.5) so I don't know which function i was calling! They told me that will fix this issue.